# Keychain Item Updates Denied After Update on Lion 

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, security, keychain, sskeychain

I have an app that stores data in the keychain which will be periodically updated. Unsurprisingly, whenever I update the application, keychain once again requires the user's permission for that build. However, keychain does not permit modification (either removing items or overwriting the contents).

Obviously this is a big problem for keychain items that need to be periodically updated.

I have absolutely no issue editing/deleting/modifying keychain items with the same build number.

Any ideas?

---

[Edit: Additions removed]

See my own answer below.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't code-signing your application. Applications which are code-signed will persist their keychain trust settings and the user will never be prompted to re-authorize the app.

Comment: Its true - I'm not yet. I had not joined the developer program as this is just a limited distribution tool. Will that solve the editing issue as well?

Comment: Possibly. I'm surprised to hear that you can't edit the items after you've gotten permission to access them from the user.

Comment: As am I. I just code signed and issued an update. I'll be able to test in a moment.

Comment: Well yes, the first code-signed version still needs the credentials. It's only when performing an update to an already-code-signed app that the keychain trust settings are preserved. Although I still have no idea about the editing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this program is specific to the development machine. Since I was receiving the update in the /Applications/ folder and was testing the update in the build directory, keychain saw two applications in different locations trying to access the same secure credentials.I do not have a way to test if this theory is the actual cause since neither keychain or sandbox spat errors.

However, deleting the applications and their keys fixed the problem.